# Convergence of non-convex optimization algorithms to an $\epsilon$-accurate solution

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization, rate-of-convergence

In non-convex optimization, the argument $x \in \mathbb R^p$ is said to obtian an $\epsilon$-accurate solution if

$$\|\nabla f(x)\|^2\leq \epsilon$$

However, with the increase of the dimension $p$, the accuracy $\epsilon$ is invariant. It seems this convergence criterion becomes stricter as $p$ increases, since the number of terms in $\nabla f(x)$ increases linearly with $p$. Is my understanding correct?

Typically we can use gradient descent to solve the problem and the corresponding convergence rate is $\mathcal O(1/\epsilon)$.

If we set $\epsilon = \mathcal O(p)$ such that the convergence criterion won't be stricter for larger $p$, then the resulting convergence rate is actually a function of $p$, which is wierd.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Michael Is it better to use $\|\nabla f(x)\|^2/p \leq \epsilon$?

Comment: You can if you want.  A lot of algorithms are designed to get an $O(\epsilon)$ approximation, meaning some constant multiple of $\epsilon$, where the constant can depend on function constants like dimension, Lipschitz parameters, and so on.  Nesterov has a way of measuring "uniformly in the dimension" which is similar in spirit to your normalization.

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot! May I know the title of the paper by Nesterov about measuring uniformly in the dimension?

Comment: Nesterov has a book: _Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization: A Basic Course_.

Comment: Actually, for nonconvex problems, you are not going to converge in $\mathcal{O}(1 / \epsilon)$ but rather you are going to converge in $\mathcal{O}(1 / \sqrt(T))$ if $T$ is the number of times that you iterated your gradient based updates, e.g., stochastic gradient descent.